# Spark SQL: If word from list of words is contained in column, return found word in new column

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to return a new column of "found" words from a list of words. I've written code the returns "T" when the word is found. How do I return the actual word?

My list of words:

['murder',
 'violence',
 'flashback',
 'cult',
 'revenge',
 'romantic',
 'comedy',
 'psychedelic',
 'suspenseful',
 'train']

Currently:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df.select(
    "*", 
    when(col("tags").rlike("|".join(list)), 'T').alias("toptags"), 
).show()

+--------------------+-------+
|                tags|toptags|
+--------------------+-------+
|cult, horror, got...|      T|
|            violence|      T|
|they dream of som...|   null|
|                imdb|   null|
|inspiring, romant...|      T|
+--------------------+-------+
```

Desired result:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|                tags|toptags|
+--------------------+-------+
|cult, horror, got...|   cult |
|            violence|violence|
|they dream of som...|   null |
|                imdb|   null |
|inspiring, romant...|romance |
+--------------------+-------+
```